# Intuitive understanding of half wave rectifier circuit

Tags: capacitor, diodes

I’m curious about the inner workings of this circuit in terms of the questions being asked. I want to develop an intuitive understanding of how it works.

[image]

Comment: Think about this: what is the maximum positive voltage that the output can produce in both scenarios?

Comment: [**SEE THIS CHAT**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148846/discussion-between-kee97-and-periblepsis) for additional valuable additional.

Comment: I've reopened this question as the answer given plus linked discussion in chat make it valuable as a resource.  I changed the subjet line to make the question more "findable".

Answer (score 2):

It may be a little easier to understand if I redraw it: (*)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8q0KH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For now, just ignore the fact that I've changed the ground reference and play along with me for a moment. My purpose here is to put an ***emphasis*** on the fact that the capacitor charges up during the first half-cycle (or the second depending) and that the DC voltage across the capacitor ***adds*** to \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$. (If you look at it, you should be able to notice with some care applied that the connections are all the same as what you have. I've just drawn the schematic, differently.)

Again, what I've emphasized in the above schematic is that the capacitor will acquire a fixed voltage across it, upon which \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$ then rests. This happens because when the polarity of \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$ forward-biases the diode then \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$ directly charges up the capacitor (less the diode drop which in your problem may be one of two possible values.) Since the forward-biased diode makes the ground-end of \$C\$ more positive, the value of \$V_{_\text{DC}}\$ will be negative with respect to ground in this altered example.

When the polarity of \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$ reverse-biases the diode then the diode doesn't conduct at all and so \$V_{_\text{DC+VIN}}\$ will be addition of the capacitor's DC level (as just charged up) and \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$.

If there's no load present to draw down the capacitor's voltage, then \$V_{_\text{DC+VIN}}\$ will add the magnitude of the forward-biasing voltage (less diode drop) that is sitting on the capacitor, which is \$V_{_\text{DC}}\$, plus \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$. So, say for example that \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$ oscillates between \$-10\:\text{V}\$ and \$+10\:\text{V}\$, then it follows (assuming an ideal diode) that \$V_{_\text{DC}}\$ will be \$-10\:\text{V}\$ and that \$V_{_\text{DC+VIN}}\$ will go from \$0\:\text{V}\$ to \$-20\:\text{V}\$.

Now, in your specific schematic, they've chosen a different ground. All this means is that the output will be the inverse, so that it would go from \$0\:\text{V}\$ to \$+20\:\text{V}\$.

This is often shown as part of a voltage doubler circuit that would look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjQDOq.png)</sup>

The first half-wave rectification stage on the left generates a DC-biased AC output, using \$C_1\$ to bias it entirely into either positive (or in this case, negative) region with respect to ground. The second half-wave rectification stage then accepts this as input and generates a DC output (negative in this case.) That output is then applied to the load.

But \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$ can be re-ordered (they are in series, after all) with \$C_1\$ without impacting the schematic meaning. So:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fErrBo.png)</sup>

That's the exact same thing. Just re-arranged slightly. But it performs the same way as before.

For all the above discussion, keep in mind that my ground reference is different from theirs. The behavior description remains, but the polarity is reversed in their case.

Also, if you flip the diodes around then the circuits still perform as before but with opposite polarities.

As a final note, let's return to the first circuit but drawn differently yet again:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTmt0o.png)</sup>

I've picked a different reference point. But now you should be able to see why the capacitor itself charges up (once) and then just stays there, charged and never changing afterwards. This is most clearly a half-wave rectifier circuit. (It always ***was*** a half-wave rectifier circuit. It's just that it is now oriented to emphasize that aspect.)

It's the same circuit. I've only changed the reference point and the node to compare it against. But now it's just a DC output. But the circuit didn't actually change. Just the perspective did. Nature itself doesn't care. It does what it does. But our thinking about it changes when we move around the two nodes that we care about, calling one a reference and the other some 'signal' or voltage node.

(*) *Something you should also do, even if at first you have little idea what the results will be -- just keep working at it to develop a sense about things.*

Comment: Thank you so much for the details! I appreciate all the analysis. I’m trying to understand everything and have a lot of questions. First question is, when Vin is at +6V, wouldn’t we charge the capacitor to 6V as well? The negative end of the capacitor is in the same node as the diode’s anode, so I don’t see how we’d forward bias the diode given we need a higher voltage w.r.t the cathode to forward bias it?

Comment: @KEE97 When using my re-arranged schematic, you cannot say that Vin is +6 V. You can only say that the *difference* between one side of Vin and the other side is +6 V. If in the first half-cycle case, the capacitor voltage is 0 V, then for this half-cycle the anode end of the diode D will be at +6 V with respect to ground. So that matches your statement. In this case, diode D will be forward biased and will charge the ground end of C to +6 V with respect to the Vdc point. This makes Vdc itself -6 V with respect to ground. Two ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: @KEE97 On the next half-cycle, Vin reverses polarity and since Vdc is at (for example) -6 V with respect to ground, this means that Vdc+vin will now be -6 V + (-6 V) = -12 V with respect to ground. This makes the diode D's anode more negative than its cathode (at ground.) So the diode does not conduct during this half-cycle. So the output will sit at -12 V.

Comment: @KEE97 During the third half-cycle, with Vdc still at -6 V, and Vin at +6 V with respect to Vdc, these two add to make Vdc+vin sit at 0 V. Since ground is also 0 V, the ideal diode is off. (Or on, doesn't matter really.) And so the output will be 0 V on this 3rd half-cycle. On the 4th half-cycle, the output will go back to -12 V. Etc. This is about ***my*** schematic!! Keep that in mind. What they did is move the ground to a different place. So all of the above still applies except the polarity is opposite.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much and apologies if I’m making you go in circles here, but in the first phase when Vin is at 6 V higher than the other end of it (like you said), wouldn’t the voltage charge up the capacitor (the side of the capacitor connected to Vin’s + terminal) so we’d have 6 volts across the capacitor but the other plate connected to the diode’s anode would be at 0, so the diode would not conduct?

Comment: @KEE97 I can't say what's blocking you. But I think it is that you imagine there exists absolute voltage values. Nothing like that exists. I could label ground as `one million volts`. Instead of zero. Everything is relative. There's no such thing as an absolute voltage. But maybe I'm wrong about what's bugging you, too. That's just my guess. But if I'm right, you need to break yourself of the idea of absolute numbers here. Voltage is always a relative thing, relative to some other place in the circuit.

Comment: I see what you mean, we could label ground as 1 million volts and then everything else would need to be adjusted to reflect that it is higher than ground (1 M V) by the same amount it was higher than ground previously (when it was 0 V). I don’t think that’s the confusion here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148846/discussion-between-kee97-and-periblepsis).

Comment: @KEE97 One more try. I've added some comments to the chat discussion. Just letting you know.

Comment: @KEE97 Just added some last thoughts into the chat space.